# Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'awswrangler'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am deploying a Python lambda to integrate with an open search endpoint. I am following this [CDK example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/constructs/aws-lambda-opensearch.html).

I have a directory containing my lambda handler as well as a `requirements.txt` file in a directory that is uploaded like this:

```
const lambdaFunction: lambda.Function = new lambda.Function(this, id, {
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
    handler: 'index.handler',
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(`lambda`)}
);
```

my `requirements.txt` has the following content:

```
awswrangler[opensearch]
boto3
```

When I invoke the lambda I get an "Internal server error" and when I review the cloudwatch logs I see the following:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'awswrangler'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I am trying to access opensearch via awswrangler but am getting a dependency error - my lambda imports look like the following:

```
import awswrangler as wr

# this is configured in CDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/constructs/aws-lambda-opensearch.html
open_search_domain_endpoint = os.environ.get('DOMAIN_ENDPOINT')
os_client = wr.opensearch.connect(
    host=open_search_domain_endpoint,
)
```

it seems as though my `requirements.txt` file is not getting installed. How can I verify my libraries are being installed to avoid this module import error.

Answer (score 0):

When we need to use a third lib, it is necessary to use the Layers functionality. We create Layers by passing a zipped file of the third libs. It's practically getting the "site-packages" generated when running pip install.

You can see more about with these links:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/chapter-layers.html
https://www.ranthebuilder.cloud/post/build-aws-lambda-layers-with-aws-cdk